# Modified version of Miller-Rabin to test deterministic primality?

Tags: algorithm, primes, proof, primality-test

The [Miller-Rabin test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) uses **k** random integers to test for primality.

According to CLRS, 3<sup>rd</sup> Edition, Page 971:

> Theorem 31.38
>
> If n is an odd composite number, then the number of witnesses to the compositeness of n is at least (n - 1)/2.

Then why don't we just instead of running *random* tests k times, use *different* ( n - 1 ) / 2 values and test them for primality? Since all primes except 2 are odd and no of witnesses are atleast ( n - 1 ) / 2 we are guaranteed to find a witness if exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The running time goes from poly(log(n)) to n*poly(log(n)), which is terrible for large numbers, since n is exponentially bigger than log(n).

Comment: But it still uses `k` tests. Is `k` chosen is really small then half of value of number ? What is the value used then?

Comment: @ABHI `k` is really small. Miller's original test, which requires the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis, sets k = O(log^2 n).